# Do I purchase a domain name first?

Tags: azure

I am completely new to Microsoft Azure. I know very little about it. I have a MVC 5 app which I created that I'd like to possibly host on Azure. Do I purchase a domain name first and then move it over to Azure? If not, how does this work?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it either way. If you create web site in Azure you get mysite.azurewebsites.net url for it, which you can then change to your domain when you purchase it.

Or you can purchase the domain name first and straight away change NS records to point over there once you move your site to Azure.

It's really flexible and there is no restrictions to it.
The process in more detail goes roughly like this:

1. When you try to set the domain name for your site, Azure gives you certain records you need to set in NS tables.
2. Where you have bought the domain name, make sure you have access to alter the NS records or contact support to do it for you.
3. Insert the 2 records Azure tells you to.
4. After the change has propagated, you will see green light in Azure as it accepts the new domain name.
5. Done!